# Pulling max values grouped by a variable with other columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have three columns in a very large table: a timestamp variable (last_time_started), a player name (Michael Jordan), and the team he was on the last time he started (Washington Wizards, Chicago Bulls), how do I pull the last time a player started, grouped by player, showing the team? For example:

[image: before table and after table]

if I did

```
select max(last_time_started), player, team
from table
group by 2
```

I would not know which team the player was on when he played his last game, which is important to me.

Comment: What RDBMS are using? Postgres, Sql Server, MySQL, ... ?

Comment: Postgres. Sorry I should've specified

Comment: It seems to me that `group by player, team` instead of `group by 2` could do the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres the most efficient way is to use `distinct on()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (player) 
       last_time_started, 
       player, 
       team, 
FROM the_table
ORDER BY player, last_time_started DESC;
```

Using a window function is usually the second fastest solution, using a join with a derived table is usually the slowest alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
select s.*
from table s
     inner join (
        select max(t.last_time_started) as last_time_started, t.player
        from table t
        group by t.player) v on s.player = t.player and s.last_time_started = t.last_time_started
```

Also this approach should be faster, because it does not contain `join`

```
select v.last_time_started,
       v.player,
       v.team
from (
    select t.last_time_started,
           t.player,
           t.team,
           row_number() over (partition by t.player order by last_time_started desc) as n
    from table t
) v
where v.n = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways to do this in Postgres:

With windowing functions:

```
SELECT last_time_started, player, team
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            last_time_started, 
            player, 
            team, 
            CASE WHEN max(last_time_started) OVER (PARTITION BY PLAYER) = last_time_started then 'X' END as max_last_time_started
        FROM table
    )
WHERE max_last_time_started = 'x';
```

Or with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT last_time_started, player, team
FROM table t1
WHERE last_time_started = (SELECT max(last_time_started) FROM table WHERE table.player = t1.player);
```